# How to upgrade other major OS to work on 3 B+

Tags: boot, raspbian-stretch, boot-issues, ubuntu, pi-3b+

**Scenario**

I am yet another victim of thinking my rpi 3 B+ was broken when it wouldn't boot up. It turns out that the 3 B+ is looking for some special boot instructions.

*I currently have:*

Ubuntu Mate 16.04 armhf - Boots on 3 NOT on 3 B+

*and*

Raspbian Stretch - Boots on 3 B+

**Question**

Is it possible to copy files from the raspbian SD card to the Ubuntu SD card in order to make Ubuntu Mate boot on 3 B+? Note, I tried copying all files except for the kernel* files with no success.

## EDIT

No idea where this guy found / created a version of Mate that runs on 3 B+ but until a version exists from Ubuntu directly you can follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7xcd3I72Gw

Or download directly using [this torrent.](http://chemio.cf/torrentech/ubuntu-on-pi3-b-plus.torrent)

It downloads as a zip and unzips as an iso. To install:

```
diskutil list
diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk[get-number-from-list]
sudo dd if=Path/to/UbuntuMate.iso of=/dev/disk[get-number-from-list] bs=1024m
```

Plugged sd card into the rpi and violá. Display, mouse, keyboard, bluetooth, wifi, it all works.

Regarding the original question I would still know how to perform the boot upgrade myself, ultimately so I can do it for [14.04 trusty](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/2015-04-06-ubuntu-trusty.zip).

## EDIT 2

The person who made the ubuntu 16 armhf iso said he just copied files over from raspbian. So far my attempts at this have failed but once I figured it out I'll post back with an answer.

Comment: the likely issue is that the kernel has some 3B+ magic in it as well

Comment: After your edit: is the question answered now?

Comment: @Ingo The answer would involve HOW to turn a regular Ubuntu Mate ISO into the one that I listed in my edit.